# page.$$ and ElementHandle traversal

Tags: puppeteer

After reading the documentation and the examples I still have problems of understanding how one can navigate through `ElementHandle` response of `page.$$`.

Most of the use cases of wanting to use `page.$$` and implicitly `document.querySelectorAll()` are to get an array or a NodeList and then work on top of that.

Let's say we have a page with 5 links and I want to print the href of the 2nd `a` in my script. This is what I've tried and it doesn't work.

```
const linksArray = await page.$$('a');
const the2ndHref = await page.evaluate(linkList => linkList[1].href, linksArray);
console.log('the2ndHref', the2ndHref);
await linksArray.dispose();
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you dont actually want an `ElementHandle` because an `ElementHandle` represents a DOM element where you can actuate with [properties](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) like `click`, `focus`, `hover`.

If you want to get the href of links, you can do something like this:

```
await page.goto('https://www.google.com/search?q=puppeteer')

const LINKS_SELECTOR = 'a'
const the2ndHref = await page.evaluate(selector => {
  const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
  return allLinks[1].href
}, LINKS_SELECTOR)

console.log('the2ndHref', the2ndHref)
```